# filtered list cartesian product without intermediate list

Tags: haskell, traversable

I am trying to create a filtered cartesian product from a given list of lists. The naive solution is the following:

```
import Data.Traversable (sequence)

predicate :: [T] -> Bool
predicate = ...

filteredCartesianProduct :: [[T]] -> [[T]]
filteredCartesianProduct = filter predicate . sequence
```

Is traversable powerful enough to do it without creating an intermediate list? Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Assuming the signature of your `predicate` function is correct, then your implementation of `filteredPowerSet` is incorrect. Why are you composing `filter predicate` with `sequence`? This doesn't typecheck. Shouldn't your implementation be `filteredPowerSet = filter predicate`?

Comment: The declared type implies that you are already receiving (or at least expecting) a powerset, not a set, as the argument.

Comment: I am recieving a list of lists, like [[1,2],[3,4,5]], sequence produces the following: [[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5]].

Comment: BTW just so you understand the confusion, `sequence` is a very common function in Haskell found in `Prelude` and `Control.Monad`: `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`

Comment: That is the function I am using. I'll edit my post to clarify this

Comment: `sequence` doesn't create a powerset. For one, it produces a list of lists if equal length.

Comment: `sequence` computes the cartesian product -- perhaps this is what you mean?

Comment: `filter` makes a single pass, to answer your question.

Comment: Yeah.. I was thinking cartesian product of course. I do not know why I wrote powerset.. Sorry everyone for the confusion.

Comment: Is something about `filter predicate . sequence` multiple-pass-y?

Comment: I think I was not clear again.. By "one pass" I meant eliminating intermediate list.

Comment: If your optimizer can't, rewrite `sequence` as an explicit list comprehension and stick the predicate in it.

Comment: I can not use list comprehension, since the input list has variable length.

Comment: `filtered_sequence _ [] = [[]]; filtered_sequence (x:xs) = [z|u<-x, us<-sequence xs, let z = u:us, f z]`. Note `f` doesn't propagate, i.e. to make this definition recursive one would write `filtered_sequence (const True) xs` inside the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

`traverse` here encodes the pattern that `predicate` has the form `all foo` for some `foo`. Then, `filteredCartesianProduct` is `traverse (filter foo)`.

If `predicate` says yes for each prefix of any list on which it says yes, you've got the backtracking pattern:

```
filteredCartesianProduct = foldlM (\accum factor -> [new | x <- factor, let new = accum ++ [x], predicate new]) []
```

I wonder how to get rid of the `++ [_]` smell.